# Are Group 2 metal fluoride salts less soluble in organic solvents than Group 1 fluorides?

Tags: solubility, halides, ionic-compounds

It is clear that Group 1 metal fluoride salts DO NOT readily form solutions in organic medium. The amount of solvation that can occur leading to the eventual release of a fluoride ion depends on many factors, one is the polarity of solvent (described by dielectric constant). Most examples seen in the literature seem to evolve around using $\ce{CsF}$ or $\ce{KF}$ in the vicinity of 18-crown-6 ether as common examples for the release of fluoride ions (not considering TBAF). However, I cant seem to find any description for $\ce{MgF2}$ or $\ce{CaF2}$ salts and how their solubility in organic medium affects the release of fluoride ions.

Answer (score 4):

Don't get your hopes up.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_fluoride) identifies magnesium fluoride as insoluble in ethanol.  [Calcium fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_fluoride) fares no differently in acetone.  While these data are hardly exhaustive, they suggest strongly that Group 2 fluorides are not a good way to get fluoride ions into solution.  Of course, we would not expect Group 2 ionic compounds with their doubly charged ions to get very far in organic solvents generally.

Getting fluoride ions into solution with organic solvents is typically done with bulky 1+ cations, such as N,N,N-trimethyl-(2,2-dimethyl-prop-1-yl)ammonium ion, $\ce{C_{8}H_{20}N^+}$.  See Reference [[1](https://millergroup.caltech.edu/Miller_Group/publications/preprints/TFMpaper99_2019_MatChemFront_VD_FIBatteries.pdf)] as an example.  The use of cryptand-complex alkali-metal complexes fits this paradigm because such ions are also bulky.

**Reference**

1.
Victoria K. Davis, Stephen Munoz, Jeongmin Kim, Christopher M. Bates, Nebojslš a Momčilović, Keith J. Billings, Thomas F. Miller III, Robert H. Grubbs and Simon C. Jones, "Fluoride-ion solvation in non-aqueous electrolyte solutions", *Mater. Chem. Front.*,
2019, **3**, 2721